# How to get data from a public database(50GB+) into python for processing

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to get data from the public database - "https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/Taxi-Trips/wrvz-psew/data", and use it on python for doing some EDA on it. The file(which I have downloaded) comes to around 80 GB. So it cant be run on pandas as it shows kernel died whenever I try to read_csv that file. What would be a good approach to read the file so I can work on it, do some EDA on the data and get some visualization using it. I have never worked with such big data so I am not sure how to start to handle it. I can do all the needed EDA if the file was smaller size and I could read it using read_csv but in this case how to get started to read the data to file.

Comment: Try [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html) instead of pandas

Comment: can I perform same pandas functions with dask, like describe and use matplotlib and do EDA? Would using big query be easy if I have an API endpoint/SODA API?

Comment: Pyspark, you can try to process in chunks, also check data types, maybe you can convert to other types and reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: Use small chunks instead of loading the data all at once. As @RJAdriaansen said, dask is a good alternative in this situation.

Comment: I am trying the chunks option in pandas, with a chunk of a million at a time. But still there is memory issue. Is it possible to convert data type while chunking? Or can it be only done after reading the entire file.